# Plot pandas dataframe using column names as x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following pandas Data Frame:
[image]

and I need to make line plots using the column names `(400, 400.5, 401....)` as the x axis and the data frame values as the y axis, and using the index column `('fluorophore')` as the label for that line plot. I want to be able to choose which `fluorophores` I want to plot.

#### How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know your dataset, so if it's always just full columns of NaN you could do

```
df[non_nan_cols].T[['FAM', 'TET']].plot.line()
```

Where `non_nan_cols` is a list of your columns that do not contain NaN values.

Alternatively, you could

```
choice_of_fp = df.index.tolist()
x_val = np.asarray(df.columns.tolist())
for i in choice_of_fp:
    mask = np.isfinite(df.loc[i].values)
    plt.plot(x_val[mask], df.loc[i].values[mask], label=i)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which allows to have NaN values. Here `choice_of_fp` is a list containing the fluorophores you want to plot.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the below and it will use all columns except the index and plot the chart.

```
abs_data.set_index('fluorophore ').plot()
```

If you want to filter values for fluorophore then you can do this

```
abs_data[abs_data.fluorophore .isin(['A', 'B'])].set_index('fluorophore ').plot()
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I get the column names as labels for the different plots